# comparing const char* vs char (can not compare using strcmp) hangman game

Tags: c++

```
int main(){

    char real_word[200];
    char entered_variable;
    int counter_1 = 0;
    int counter_2 = 0;

    cout << "Enter The Word (It will be hidden throughout the game) :  ";
    cin.getline(real_word, sizeof(real_word));
    cout << string(50, '\n'); // clear screen

    for (counter_1 = 0; counter_1 < strlen(real_word); counter_1++){
        cout << "_ ";
        // cout << endl << real_word[counter_1]; JUST a control line
    }
    for (counter_1 = 0; counter_1 < strlen(real_word); counter_1++){

        cout << endl << "Please enter the first letter: ";
        cin >> entered_variable;
        for (counter_2 = 0; counter_2 < strlen(real_word); counter_2++){
            if (strcmp(real_word[counter_1], entered_variable) == 0)
            {
                cout << entered_variable;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "_ ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`if (strcmp(real_word[counter_1], entered_variable) == 0)` causes this error:

```
Error   4   error C2664: 'int strcmp(const char *,const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'const char *'  */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) is a function for comparing whole C-style strings. If you want to compare single characters, simply use `==`:

```
if(real_word[counter_1] == entered_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be using `strcmp` here, it's for comparing  strings.  Just see if the `char`s match, something like:

```
if (real_word[counter_1] == entered_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` compares strings (zero terminated character arrays) and not characters. And while a string can consist of only a single character, they are still distinct types (like an array containing one integer is different from a single integer variable).

For comparing two characters  (a single character from the word and the guard character) just use the `==` operator:

```
if (real_word[counter_1] == entered_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `strcmp()` expects a `const char *` as an argument, but that is not what you are providing (  `entered_variable` is not `const char *`) . You actually don't need to use `strcmp()` for this. It can be easily achieved using

```
if ( real_word[counter_1] == entered_variable )
```

Now, I also don't understand for what reason you need so many for loop in this code, like the 3rd one as it just prints the same character many times ( which I don't think you need for this )

Answer (score 0):

From [here:](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

> int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );

This is the prototype of strcmp, which shows that strcmp requires `char *` as second parameter, whereas `entered_variable` is `char`. So, you cannot use it here. You might have to use another approach to compare them.